# Meta and link tags missing inside head after vuetify update

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

So I'm running an application with Nuxtjs/Vue and recently we decided to update vuetify to the latest version (2.0), but something strange is happening.

While the user navigate through, everything works just fine and all the meta and link tags are inside head tag, but when the user open the right navigation drawer the icon that was working and his action were open the drawer turns into text [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1YBX.png) and the whole system lose the imported google font (https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons) and display the default font [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T09n8.png). The way that were supposed to be: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiqYY.png).

As you can see most of icons turns into text too [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7W0t.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46ZCU.png) , but the strangest thing here is that if I right click on the navigation drawer all the meta and link tags that were gone when he clicked to open the navigation drawer return to the head tag and everything now works until I click to open the drawer again.

I mentioned the vuetify update because when we were using 1.3.x everything was working perfectly and we never had something like this before.

I'm almost sure that is something about the way that [this is being imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MImv.png) but i didn't find anything useful about this in the documentation neither other places and I don't know if this is related to vuetify too.

Obs.: Not all icons turns into text when this happens only material design icons

The question here is why are the meta and link tags missing on click and how is it possible they return too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer for this. For some reason after update vuetify, all tags that were generated by nuxt, were not being generated correctly. Knowing this I installed vue-meta

`npm install vue-meta --save`

Now evertything is perfect.